# Nginx 403 forbidden using Location directive on PHP file

Tags: php, nginx

Here's my server block:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    root /www/html;
    index index.php;

    location = / {
        autoindex on;
        index index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~*\.(css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
        root /www/html/shared;
        rewrite ^/releases(.*)$ $1 last;
        expires 5m;
    }

    location ~* \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }
}
```

Right now, doing this will just spit out a "403 Forbidden" error when I attempt to access "localhost/". However, the page works perfectly fine if I access it directly-- "localhost/index.php". I can't for the life of me figure out why. The error.log doesn't give me any helpful info nor an error code either--only that the page is "forbidden".
Here's the thrown error:

```
2017/03/29 14:37:35 [error] 11980#8840: *94 directory index of "C:/www/html/" is forbidden, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
```

This is a **windows-based** nginx server.

Comment: Try: `location / { ... }` without the `=`. Also, remove `autoindex on;`.

Comment: gave that a go, but it didn't seem to have changed the output.

Answer (score 0):

the answer was kind of disappointing to discover, but i'm gonna answer it so if anyone encounters this goofy issue they can fix it.

php was lookng for files with the prefix "/www/html", NOT "/www/html/", as a result when it wanted my index it was trying to load "/www/htmlindex.php" instead of "/www/html/index.php".

you can fix this by doing either

```
 fastcgi_index /index.php;
```

or adding a / to the end of your root.